# php codeigniter ajax post

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, post

I have a problem with ajax post to codeigniter controller. It is get in to function but not post the data. Why ajax is not successfully post data ?

Here is my controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    public function login(){
        if ($_POST) {
            $kAdi = $this->input->post('kAdi');
            echo json_encode("done!");
        }
    }
}?>
```

my Ajax code :

```
function girisYap(){

var kAdi = $("#username").val();
var parola = $("#password").val();    

$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "/main/login",
      data:  "kAdi="+kAdi,
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(cevap){
        alert("successfull"); 
      }
  });
}
```

Am I missing something ?

I solve the porblem, thank you guys. Here is the works code :

### The controller

```
public function login(){
        if ($_POST) {
            $kAdi = $this->input->post('kAdi');
            echo json_encode("done!");
        }
```

### Ajax function :

```
function girisYap(){
var $_base_url = '<?=base_url()?>';
var kAdi = $("#username").val();
var parola = $("#password").val();

alert($_base_url+"main/login");
$.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: $_base_url + "main/login",
  data:  {kAdi: kAdi},
  dataType: 'json',
  success : function(cevap){
     alert(cevap); 
    }
  });

}
```

Don't put the `/` before `main/login` because base `url = localhost/codeigniter/` has a slash in the end. If you put slash it become codeigniter//main....

So, thanks for all the answers.

Comment: What error you got while posting your data. Have you check your browser console????

Comment: There is no error :/ and console log empty

Comment: try with `$arr = array('done');

echo json_encode($arr);`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
function girisYap(){

var kAdi = $("#username").val();
var parola = $("#password").val();


$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/main/login",
      data:{kAdi: kAdi},
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(cevap){

        alert("successfull"); 

      }
});

}
```

Comment: What error you got while posting your data ? Would you please check console log to make sure that there is no error ? Do you have any other JS error in that page from other 3rd party script error?

Comment: yes actually i have an error log like this : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jcarousel is not a function

and this is that errors script :
<script src="../js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I think you have a jcarousel in home page or any other page except this page, if this is true then don't load jacrousel related stuffs in this page. Therefore if you are using jcarousel in this page also then it is not proper initialized. please check this

Comment: I remove jcarousel and still ajax not work :/ I dont know why this happened. I was made it successfully with pure php (without codeigniter) .

Comment: Please make sure another thing that you don't have any trailing slash in your base url

Comment: Please make sure girisYap method is firing when you click on login button.

Answer (score 0):

Post data should be like below one

```
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
```

Not like

```
  data:  "kAdi="+kAdi,
```

Also Print the URl and check it access or not

Comment: Thanks but not worked. Also i was use this "kAdi="+kAdi syntax with pure php . But i think the issue is not that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>main/login",
    {
       kAdi: kAdi                
    },
    function(cevap){
    console.log(cevap.trim());
    if(cevap){
     alert(cevap);
     alert("sucessful");
    }
    });
```

On the other hand in controller,use this

```
$this->input->post('kAdi');
```